# Add multiple products to cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart

I am able to get my last order thanks to this code:

```
    $collection = $this->collection->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
//        echo "<pre>".print_r($collection->getLastItem()->getData(), true)."</pre>"; //show data of last quote
        $quoteId = $collection->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id'); //get id of last quote
        echo "quote id : " . $quoteId;

        $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
        $products = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getData();
//        echo "<pre>".print_r($products, true)."</pre>"; //show data of last quote

        $productsRenew = array();
        foreach($products as $product){
            $productsRenew[] = array(
              'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'qty' => $product['qty'],
                'price' => $product['price'],
                'sku' => $product['sku'],
                'name' => $product['name'],
            );
        }
        echo "<pre>".print_r($productsRenew, true)."</pre>"; //show items data
```

I also got the products detail, now I want to put products details inside the cart.

I've used this to add product one by one on one on my page:

```
public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
```

Now I want to add several products in a row, but I don't know how to do this.

EDIT : solution :

```
        $customerId  = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $collection = $this->collection->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
    $quoteId = $collection->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id'); //get id of last quote

    $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
    if ($quoteId) {
        try {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
            $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
        $this->_checkoutsession->replaceQuote($quote);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to reactivate the quote(with products):

```
$quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
if ($quote->getId()) {
    $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
    $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
}
```

Also you need to inject the class **\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session** to your contruct function and then you can use the **$this->checkoutSession**

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. It's even more simple than what I've done. Great ! Thanks !

Comment: I've change 1 little part because save() is deprecated, we need to use quoteRepository->save($quote)

Comment: Thats fine. Happy to Help!.

Comment: This is working perfectly, but if I create a quote, then delete a product and after reload last quote, this isn't working

Comment: Yes because that is now changed with your new quote.

Comment: How can I avoid this with a message like "you're product is not available" ?

Comment: When I submit my quote, the quote is not register properly (i have one row Active with 0 product) and after this row, another row with the right number of product but not active